# Should net.Conn transform function retain the original data segmentation?

Tags: go

To clarify, a `net.Conn` `transform()` function transforms data write to/read from a connection, an example is as follow:

```
type TransformedConn struct {
  net.Conn
}

func (c *TransformedConn) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
  n, err := c.Conn.Read(p)
  transform(p)
  return n, err
}

func (c *TransformedConn) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
  t := append([]byte{}, p...) // as `p` must not be modified per io.Writer doc
  transform(t)
  return c.Conn.Write(t)
}
```

Similarly, `crypto/cipher.StreamReader` and `crypto/cipher.StreamWriter` perform a similar operation.

As required by `io.Writer.Write()`, it cannot modify the input buffer.  In case the size of the buffer is huge, creating a buffer of the same size will be very expensive.  So I'm wondering if it's ok for such transform function to write data out in smaller chunks, to allow us using a smaller scratch space?

I've found such chunking technique will cause some program to fail, especially the ones use `io.ReadFull()` and `io.ReadAtLeast()`. Because they implicitly expect that the data to arrive will from a single `read()` call.

Could someone point me a doc or a spec on how to write such transform functions?

Thanks!

Comment: The individual writes don't need to match in size, otherwise `bufio.Writer` wouldn't really work at all.

Comment: Side note: why not just use `copy()` instead of an append to a blank slice?

Comment: @Kaedys: appending to an empty slice is just shorthand for a `make` then `copy`.

Comment: @JimB sounds fair. But when deal with a net.Conn, fragmentation will break lots of things.  One option I can think of is to add some continuous flags to the fragment, and the the transformer to handle them and restore the original fragment to the upper level reader... However this sounds less ideal.

Comment: What things do you think will break? You can’t be using UDP, because your individual datagrams wouldn’t be that big anyway, and TCP is a stream oriented protocol